# Can telegram Bot to create an chat (group) as administrator and to give access by link?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I did'nt find answer in the manual https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api.  Can telegram bot create an groups (chats)?

Answer (score 0):

Telegram bot can't create a chat (group) or a channel.
Only users can do that.

For additional information, you can do some actions in your telegram account by API. It named "userbot". Then, userbots can create chats and channels.